# There is no 'the' in 'in liver of rhesus monkeys'

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

I have read a title of a paper on pubmed like this: Aging increases mitochondrial DNA damage and oxidative stress **in liver of rhesus monkeys**.

(source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22027539)

---

Since articles are words that define a noun as specific or unspecific, and it has indicated this paper is about the specific liver of rhesus monkey, so what I think the correct title is: Aging increases mitochondrial DNA damage and oxidative stress **in the livers of rhesus monkeys** (or **in the liver of rhesus monkey**). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the definite article were only missing in the title, I might be inclined to accept the idea that it was simply abbreviated writing, commonly called [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese).

Looking at the Abstract, it is clear that the authors are referring to liver tissue, rather than to complete organs. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tissue), **tissue** is uncountable, and so **liver** used in the sense of **liver tissue** would also be uncountable. Usage of the definite article would therefore be incorrect. Here are two quotes from the the abstract:

> We measured mitochondrial DNA (mtDNA) damage by quantitative PCR in **liver** and peripheral blood mononuclear cells of young, middle age, and old monkeys and show that older monkeys have increases in the number of mtDNA lesions.
>
> **Liver** from older monkeys showed significant increases in lipid peroxidation, protein carbonylations and reduced antioxidant enzyme activity.

Comment: But, even 'liver' here means liver tissue that is uncountable, it still indicates the specific liver tissue of rhesus monkeys, why can't say 'in the liver of rhesus monkeys'?

Comment: @sdasdtont, If you say **the liver**, you are referring to the organ. You could say "the liver of a rhesus monkey", but if you are talking about more than one monkey, you would have to say "the livers of rhesus monkeys"

Answer (score 1):

"in liver" could refer to organ *tissue*. Or it could simply be a deliberately terse title, which doesn't reflect the spoken idiom, an analogue of "headline" writing.

A native speaker not trying to be extra-terse might say "in the *livers* of rhesus monkeys" and mean in the *organs* from a group of specimens of that species or "in the liver of rhesus monkeys" and mean in the organ (which all have).